# Implementing a Flume Sink

Tags: flume

So, I need to implement my own Flume sink. I went through this [link](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeDeveloperGuide.html#sink), but my only missing part is, what do I exactly do once I am done with my Java implementation? Compile it into a .class? JAR? and how to I configure Flume to use my custom sink?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile it and package it into a jar. Then put the jar in `<apache flume install dir>/lib`. Then you can refer to your class with its fully qualified name in a sink definition.

Comment: should it be: `<apache flume install dir>/plugins.d/custom-source-1/lib` instead? At least starting Flume 1.4.0?

Comment: I believe that that is only in 1.5 which is unreleased. This is despite the current user guide at flume.apache.org saying that it's for 1.4.0.

Comment: Just tried it on 1.4.0, worked smoothly with the plugins.d folder.. Thanks anyway