# Where to place custom jars in Apache Flume 1.5?

Tags: java, flume

I need to create a custom source in flume for which i have provided the fully qualified class name in the conf file.But I am unable to figure out as to where I need to place the jar file.
After reading several posts ,I created a "plugins.d" folder within the Flume directory and placed my jar there.Still during start up ,it is unable to load the jar.
Should I modify the flume-env.sh ?

Comment: Is this not a near duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856585/implementing-a-flume-sink/21872243#21872243?

Comment: I have read that post before posting.I am unable to figure out the location of plugins.d

Answer (score 2):

In flume-env.sh add this:

> FLUME_CLASSPATH="/path/to/your/jar:/path/to/another/jar"

Answer (score 0):

From the Flume [documentation](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html):

> The plugins.d directory is located at **`$FLUME_HOME/plugins.d`**